# HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" not working in TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Here's an example where it is not working:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">Some random text</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

I want the text box to stretch to the width of the window, but instead you get this:

[image: what it looks like]

[image: what it looks like at runtime]

The textbox expands as you type, which is not what I want.

I am thinking now it might be possible to set a binding on the width of the 2nd column to the width of the `TreeViewItem` but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried putting the grid in assorted panels, but that doesn't work either. I have also set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` on the textbox itself, but that also doesn't work.

Is this some limitation of the `Grid` control? Putting a textbox in a tree view by itself will make it expand as I want, but I need the label to be next to it and if there are multiple fields it looks MUCH better if all the textboxes are aligned.

**UPDATE**

Using a different `ControlTemplate` allows headers to stretch but contents still don't stretch.

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeViewItem Style="{DynamicResource StretchableTreeViewItemTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Stuff">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">Some random text</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>



<Style x:Key="StretchableTreeViewItemTemplate" TargetType="TreeViewItem"
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
      Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                            MinWidth="19" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--
                         Note that the following do not work, but I believe the top 2 should?!
                         <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                         <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Property=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                         <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Path=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                    -->
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      ClickMode="Press"
                      Name="Expander">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable"
                      Value="false" />
                                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width"
                      Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height"
                      Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                    <Border Padding="5,5,5,5"
                            Background="#00FFFFFF"
                            Width="16"
                            Height="16">
                                                        <Path Fill="#00FFFFFF"
                            Stroke="#FF989898"
                            Name="ExpandPath">
                                                            <Path.Data>
                                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                            </Path.Data>
                                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="135"
                                           CenterX="3"
                                           CenterY="3" />
                                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Path>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver"
                               Value="True">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Shape.Stroke"
                                Value="#FF1BBBFA" />
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Shape.Fill"
                                Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
                               Value="True">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="UIElement.RenderTransform">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                             CenterX="3"
                                             CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Shape.Fill"
                                Value="#FF595959" />
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Shape.Stroke"
                                Value="#FF262626" />
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Grid.Column="1">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded"
               Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems"
               Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected"
               Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                Property="Panel.Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected"
                     Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                     Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                Property="Panel.Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
               Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Results:

[image: with control template edited]

Trying with Pikoh's solution:

```
<local:StretchingTreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <local:StretchingTreeViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Stuff">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0">Some random text</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </local:StretchingTreeViewItem>
</local:StretchingTreeView>
```

[image: results with Pikoh's solution]

Comment: Works fine for me? You must have set some other property also. Are you sure you have given the right code?

Comment: If you can give me an idea where to look for any extra properties like that, I'd be more than happy to check but this is as much code as I've got. I didn't touch the code behind file either, I just made a new project in VS2015 and slapped this in there. I am using .NET 4.5 if that matters.

Comment: See my answer or @BradleyUffner's, I think both of them will work

Comment: Well, in the sample project i've done using the inherited class provided in my answer, it stretches just fine, with the textbox expanded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
```

**Edit**

Ok,i've found one solution [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2008/08/05/wpf-a-stretching-treeview.aspx). It basically creates a new class inheriting Treeview:

```
class StretchingTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new StretchingTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is StretchingTreeViewItem;
    }
}

class StretchingTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    public StretchingTreeViewItem()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(StretchingTreeViewItem_Loaded);
    }

    private void StretchingTreeViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The purpose of this code is to stretch the Header Content all the way accross the TreeView. 
        if (this.VisualChildrenCount > 0)
        {
            Grid grid = this.GetVisualChild(0) as Grid;
            if (grid != null && grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count == 3)
            {
                // Remove the middle column which is set to Auto and let it get replaced with the 
                // last column that is set to Star.
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new StretchingTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is StretchingTreeViewItem;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

    <local:StretchingTreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

        <local:StretchingTreeViewItem Header="Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">Some random text</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" ></TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </local:StretchingTreeViewItem>
    </local:StretchingTreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Almost, but it is stretching off the bounds of the Window.

Comment: Looks like it is causing the grid to stretch constantly. I'm monitoring the grid width and it is increasing very quickly.

Comment: Hmm,you're right. I think this is a known issue, and it has no simple solution. I'm trying to find one

Comment: Ok, you must add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the `local:StretchingTreeViewItem` tag

Comment: You're welcome :) Maybe Bradley Uffner's solutions also works for you adding the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: nope, doesn't work with that. I'll stick to the subclass.

Answer (score 6):

The core of the issue (and the way to fix it) is described [here](https://leecampbell.com/2009/01/14/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems/):

The default `ControlTemplate` for the `TreeViewItem` uses a grid of 3 columns x 2 rows, defined such that the content cannot stretch horizontally. The author also gives a modified style, that changes the grid so that the content can stretch.

Note that the modified style sets the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `TreeViewItem` to `Center`, and that the `ControlTemplate` uses this property for aligning the content.

To achieve the desired effect, either set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` in the modified style, or override ***just that property*** on the `TreeView` (or specific `TreeViewItems`).

Missing the `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"` part causes the TreeViewItem to revert to using the default `ControlTemplate`, with the non-stretchable grid.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

In a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, the effect would be achieved by using the `ItemContainerStyle` property.

@pikoh's method of deriving from `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` achieves the same, by modifying the grid from code.

Complete example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                MinWidth="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!-- Note that the following do not work, but I believe the top 2 should?! -->
                                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable" Value="false" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Border Padding="5,5,5,5" Background="#00FFFFFF" Width="16" Height="16">
                                                            <Path Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#FF989898" Name="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Path.Data>
                                                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                                </Path.Data>
                                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                            </Path>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF1BBBFA" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="UIElement.RenderTransform">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#FF595959" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF262626" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd"  Property="Panel.Background"  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">Some random text</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 4):

Due to an odd design decision by Microsoft when creating WPF, tree items can't stretch without replacing the control template.

See http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html

The required style is:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <StackPanel>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                MinWidth="19" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--
                             Note that the following do not work, but I believe the top 2 should?!
                             <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                             <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Property=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                             <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Path=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                        -->
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          ClickMode="Press"
                          Name="Expander">
              <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                  <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable"
                          Value="false" />
                  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width"
                          Value="16" />
                  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height"
                          Value="16" />
                  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Padding="5,5,5,5"
                                Background="#00FFFFFF"
                                Width="16"
                                Height="16">
                          <Path Fill="#00FFFFFF"
                                Stroke="#FF989898"
                                Name="ExpandPath">
                            <Path.Data>
                              <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                            </Path.Data>
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                              <RotateTransform Angle="135"
                                               CenterX="3"
                                               CenterY="3" />
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                          </Path>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Property="Shape.Stroke"
                                    Value="#FF1BBBFA" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Property="Shape.Fill"
                                    Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
                                   Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Property="UIElement.RenderTransform">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                                 CenterX="3"
                                                 CenterY="3" />
                              </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Property="Shape.Fill"
                                    Value="#FF595959" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Property="Shape.Stroke"
                                    Value="#FF262626" />
                          </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                </Style>
              </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Grid.Column="1">
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1" />
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                    Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="Panel.Background"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
          </Trigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                         Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="Panel.Background"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This seems to work for the `TreeViewItem`'s header itself, but not for its contents. I'll update OP with pictures.

Comment: I've used this in the past and it's always worked for me, though I've never had anything more complicated than a simple textblock inside the items.  It might be due to your more complex layout needs. If you use something that allows you to inspect the live elements, like Snoop, does it show the item template taking the full width?

Answer (score 4):

***It*** seems like `Grid's` `HorizontalAlignment` Issue. I've tried it in .`Net` `Framework` 4 and it all works fine. Seems like in 4.5 even though you specify `HorizontalAlignment` as `Stretch`, it actually doesn't stretch it. So you can do a binding like below:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},Path=ActualWidth,Mode=OneTime}"
              >
```

Cause you can see in the run time that TreeViewItem has Width expected but Grid doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm. I did try it in 4.6.1 and 3.5 but I didn't try 4. I'll try again tomorrow in the morning, I might be able to get away with this assembly building in 4. Will the fact that the rest of my app be in 4.5 have any effect?

Comment: @Logan no it should cause any compatibility issue. but I'm not so sure that you will able to solve your problem like that.Cause at the runtime app will be using WPF components from 4.5(just an assumption) :(... it's better you handle it with a code or binding.

Comment: I just tried in .NET 4 and it still doesn't work... interesting, perhaps it is environmental for you? Also. the binding causes the treeview to get stuck in a loop of expanding, because it expands its size based on contents and the contents keep growing as the treeview expands.

Comment: @Logan If you don;t want it to expand, you can set the mode to Mode=OneTime

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank you. However, after expanding the tree view items to the entire tree view width I got to the conclusion that I can't open anymore the right click context menu of the tree view itself. Instead I will always open the the right click context menu of the tree view item.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `Grid.ColumnSpan='2'` to the `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem` as shown below.

[image]

Thats it!

Explanation:
The default `ControlTemplate` places the Header Content in a Grid column that does not stretch. The `Grid.ColumnSpan='2'` instructs the Header content to span to the rest of the Grid.