# How can I give background color here in treeview in complete width?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have tried with HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" attribute in the stack panel, which is also not doing it.
The only Way I can do it now by giving a fixed Width of stack panel but I don't want that.

How can I set the with of this treeview templete's background the whole window streched?

[image]

```html
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyTexts}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Green">
                        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Default.imageLocation}" ></Image>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Location}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the style of the TreeViewItem objects with the "ItemContainerStyle" property of the "TreeView" itself?

Comment: A stackpanel works like an elastic band. It's only ever going to be as wide as it's content.

Comment: https://wpf.2000things.com/2017/09/23/1218-stretching-items-in-treeview-across-entire-control/

Answer (score 1):

Update your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to use a different layout panel. Instead of a `StackPanel` which will only size itself to fit its children, try using a `DockPanel` or a `Grid` with two columns:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Image ... DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <Label ... DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
</DockPanel>
```

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image ... Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label ... Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Also, the default control template for the TreeViewItem limits the width of the header. So you'll need to modify the control template to fix it. This SO question has the answers you need:

[HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" not working in TreeViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556975/horizontalalignment-stretch-not-working-in-treeviewitem)

Comment: Grid is also behaving fitting itself to fit its children.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional information to help you solve the issue.